# Change react-script test to run with .env.development instead of .env.test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I have tried

```
dotenv_config_path=./.env.development react-scripts test
```

But it still doesn't use .env.development

how can I force `react-scripts test` to run with content from `.env.development`

Comment: I don't remember if it works with CRA setup but did you try `NODE_ENV=development react-scripts test`?

Comment: @EstusFlask yeah, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/environment-variables), `NODE_ENV` in Jest defaults to `test` but can be changed with environment variable.

create-react-app provides an opinionated Jest setup. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v4.0.1/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js#L12-L24), `NODE_ENV` is forced to be `test`. Possible options are to eject, or reinitialize `dotenv` in Jest global setup or test file, or make `process.env.NODE_ENV` read-only so it couldn't be redefined by `react-scripts`, e.g.:

```
node -r ./test-dev-env.js ./node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js
```

Where test-dev-env.js is:

```
Object.defineProperty(process.env, 'NODE_ENV', { value: 'development', writable: false });
```